# how to produce shrink-wrapped external diagrams

Tags: formatting

I'm new here. As the layout editor of the electronic journal [LMCS](http://www.lmcs-online.org/index.php) sitting on top of arxiv resp. CoRR, sometimes I encounter the problem that the TeX-implementation there does not produce the same output as I'm getting (with a clean installation of texlive2013).  Sometimes even the number of pages changes :-(

Currently a paper contains two TikZ-diagrams that do not render correctly at CoRR.  Unfortunately, I cannot use TikZ's externalization to produce separate pdf-files here that could be read in at CoRR, as the diagrams are built in a 2-step process with the tikzoverlay construct: all the building blocks are externalized, but the combined diagram fails :-(

What I'm looking for is a TeX-style that allows me to render the diagrams in question in a shrink-wrapped way, with all white space removed, i.e., just in the size of the bounding box.  Alternatively, shrink-wrapping the resulting pdf-files for the individual diagrams would also help.  Obviously, I would like to avoid extracting the diagrams as image files (which I know how to do).  I have not found a way to extract them as pdf-files.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Please supply a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) whenever you pose a question. To support the effectiveness of the Q&A forum, we do not use greetings or thanks in our questions. This may seem to be rude, but this is common here because it helps to find the real question.

Comment: Are there any news here? Right now, the question seems to be unclear for me.